# OpenGL Blending GL_SRC_COLOR/GL_DST_COLOR

Tags: opengl, alphablending

Is there a way to specify either `{GL_SRC_COLOR, xxx}` and `{xxx, GL_DST_COLOR}` so that the colours of the source and destination are multiplied and also ensure that if GL_SRC_ALPHA = 0 that the result is `{GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}`?

I'm making an overlaying rectangle over my game world which starts off transparent but as time elapses into night the overlay becomes a combination of dark blue and the underlying colours.

I have tried `{GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}` among others, shown below. In both pictures, the left side is daytime without the overlay, the right side with the overlay.

*Night time is on the right, overlay (SRC) at full alpha*

[image: 1]

*Day time with the overlay is on the right at 0 alpha.*

[image: 2]

The problem is that with SRC alpha equal to zero the destination colour is doubled. I would like it to remain the same as without the overlay, so that I can adjust only the opacity during the game and transition into night. Is there a way to do this, or another way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. It's easier than using an alpha actually. I used this for the overlay:

```
{GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}
```

Initially when you have daytime, you don't want any color change at all, so you set the color of your overlay to `{255,255,255}` (white). The alpha isn't used and isn't important. This color is then multiplied by the destination color (the world background). As night time approaches, you can tint the world to any color you want by adjusting only the color of your overlay. If you want a dark blue, then you should adjust the other channels (red and green) down, leaving relatively more of the blue channel in the destination (world background). Here's the effect of setting the color to `{120, 150, 200}`.

[image: 1]